# .htaccess code showing 500 internal error

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hi there I'm trying to make a blog demo and I'm having some pretty URL codes already.

i am having a url `www.xyz.com`

and a search url `www.xyz.com/search/this+is+a+search+text`

in search url the parameter `search` is a page name and `this+is+a+search+text` is a parameter that i'll be parsing

I'm having a .htaccess code below already

```
# code to make pretty URLS | we're using this code to achieve /category/slug
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/([\w-]+)/([\d]+)$ app/post.php?&category=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)$ app/post.php?&category=$2&slug=$3 [L,QSA]

# code to make pretty URLS for search page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/([\w-]+)/([\d]+)$ app/search.php?&searchstring=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/([\d]+)$ app/index.php?page=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/([\w-]+)$ app/post.php?category=$2 [L]
```

I'm using the below code for serach page

```
# code to make pretty URLS for search page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/([\w-]+)/([\d]+)$ app/search.php&searchstring=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]
```

But while using the code I get a 500 internal error message, I'm not able to figure out what's the error!

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me out with this logic.

Comment: Please check your error log file there will be more info about the 500 error.

Comment: it says `[Sun Apr 14 00:24:04.450503 2019] [core:error] [pid 7204:tid 1244] [client ::1:11856] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://www.myblog.com/diy`

Comment: Have you done what this log message suggests? Setting the `LogLevel debug` of your might get you closer to an answer on why the internal redirect keeps happening.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: Your rules are conflicting from each other. It would be better to write requirements clearly so that you get better help in refactoring your rules.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrites in achieve /category/slug and for search page are the same. Search request matched with first - achieve rewrite and run app/post.php...

Comment: can you help me with updated code, so that I can understand where am I wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**To answer your followup question to JarekBaran**

> JarekBaran: Rewrites in achieve /category/slug and for search page are the same.

What this means is that the `RewriteCond` are the same for the pretty URL code for the caterogy/slug page and the search page.

This means that the first match will always be used and so:

`RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/([\w-]+)/([\d]+)$ app/post.php?&category=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]`

will always be triggered before

`RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/([\w-]+)/([\d]+)$ app/search.php?&searchstring=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]`

This way you will not be able to use the search function. You could consider adding a parameter to identify if a search is made or not.

Comment: There is no need to escape slashes in htaccess regex as `/` is treated as a lateral character not a delimiter.

Comment: so what do you suggest, how should i update the code to make it work? i want `www.xyz.com/search/` as a url parameter initially, then i'll add the parameters

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that you are starting your rules with `(.+)` which will match one or more of anything. This means that you are also matching the `/` character. Some of your 2 parameter redirects are matching your urls with 3 parameters because of this. You would be better of starting with something like this - `([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)`

Your search rewrite should probably be something like this - `RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([\w+]+)/([\d]+)$ app/search.php?&searchstring=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]`

I tested that rewrite on [this htaccess testing tool](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) and it is working.

That said your other rules will need to be changed as well since they all start with `(.+)`. After doing that your category rewrite will conflict with your search rewrite.

However, this would probably work for you:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^/?category/([\w-]+)/([\d]+)$ app/post.php?&category=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^/?category/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)$ app/post.php?&category=$2&slug=$3 [L,QSA]

 # code to make pretty URLS for search page
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^/?search/([\w+]+)/([\d]+)$ app/search.php?&searchstring=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([\d]+)$ app/index.php?page=$2 [L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^/?category/([\w-]+)$ app/post.php?category=$2 [L]
```

Comment: not working, still an internal 500 error stating too many internal redirects

Comment: If you are still getting that then you didn't use the whole block of code I put up there. I just tried it. It did the redirect. I checked the url that the redirect would have created and it did not match to any of the rules.